# Reposition the toolbar of quill text editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, quill

I want to detach the toolbar of quill text editor from its default position and place it in an entirely separate div. How do I do that?

Also I want to edit the order and which tools are shown after placing the toolbar in separate div.

note: I'm using theme snow

Comment: Are you using the plain Quill or some framework package?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom toolbar element and [register it with Quill](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/).

Example code from the [docs](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#container):

```html
<!-- Create toolbar container -->
<div id="toolbar">
  <!-- Add font size dropdown -->
  <select class="ql-size">
    <option value="small"></option>
    <!-- Note a missing, thus falsy value, is used to reset to default -->
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="large"></option>
    <option value="huge"></option>
  </select>
  <!-- Add a bold button -->
  <button class="ql-bold"></button>
  <!-- Add subscript and superscript buttons -->
  <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
  <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>

<!-- Initialize editor with toolbar -->
<script>
  var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
    modules: {
      toolbar: '#toolbar'
    }
  });
</script>
```

To get the HTML for the toolbar, you can use your browser Devtools to copy your existing toolbar. With a custom toolbar, you can also move buttons around and style them however you want.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having the same questions and are using React, this is very simple:

I created a very basic CustomToolbar because I needed the toolbar to be at the bottom instead of the top.

```js
const CustomToolbar = () => {
  return (
    <div id="toolbar">
      <button className="ql-bold"></button>
      <button className="ql-italic"></button>
    </div>
  );
};

const YourMainComponent = () => {
 return (
  <ReactQuill
   theme="snow"
   value={value}
   onChange={setValue}
   modules={{ toolbar: { container: '#toolbar' } }}
  />

  <CustomToolbar />
 )
}
```

Since I wanted the toolbar to be at the bery bottom so I rendered it after the actual `ReactQuill`.